# Laravel 4.2 Join Table and Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, pagination

i learn **Laravel 4.2** and try to use join table and pagination.
My code work when use pagination. But when i combine with join table it not works.

Here is my Controller :
**BookController.php**

```
public function index()
    {
        // Get All Books
        //$booksList = Book::all();
        $booksList = Book::with('category')->paginate(2);

        return View::make('books.index', compact('booksList'));
    }
```

And i get error like this :

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::category()
```

My **Category Model** just like this :

```
<?php 
    class Category extends Eloquent
    {

    }
```

My **Book model** like this :

```
<?php 
    class Book extends Eloquent
    {
        protected $fillable = array('isbn', 'title', 'author', 'publisher', 'language');
    }
```

And in **index.blade.php** :

```
<tr>
            <td>{{ $book->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $book->isbn }}</td>
            <td>{{ $book->category_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $book->title }}</td>
            <td>{{ $book->author }}</td>
            <td>{{ $book->publisher }}</td>
            <td>@if ($book->language == 1) {{ 'English' }} @else {{ 'Indonesian' }} @endif</td>
            <td>
                {{ link_to_route('books.show', 'Read', array($book->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs')) }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ link_to_route('books.edit', 'Edit', array($book->id), array('class'=>'btn btn-warning btn-xs')) }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ Form::open(array('method'=>'DELETE', 'route'=>array('books.destroy', $book->id))) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Delete', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-xs', 'onclick' => 'return confirm("Are you sure?")')) }}

                {{ Form::close() }}
            </td>
        </tr>
```

My Table Structure like this :
[image]

[image]

Please help thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the code of your Book model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with('category')` doesn't mean a join but **eager loading**

It will actually perform a join to eager load your data **BUT** you have to define relations for your models in order for laravel to understand what to do.

In short, you can only use `with()` on existing model relationships. In your case you should change your models as follows:

***Category***

```
class Category extends Eloquent
{
  public function books(){
    return $this->hasMany('Book');
  }
}
```

***Book***

```
class Book extends Eloquent
{
  protected $fillable = array('isbn', 'title', 'author', 'publisher', 'language');

  public function category(){ 
    return $this->belongsTo('Category');
  }
}
```

More on Laravel [Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)

Answer (score 3):

When you using join in eloquent you have to implement the relation withing the models like this :

```
<?php 
class Book extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = array('isbn', 'title', 'author', 'publisher', 'language');

     public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
     }

}
```

and

```
<?php 
class Category extends Eloquent
{
    public function book(){
        return $this->hasMany('Category');
     }
}
```